# Get Jira to run on shared Windows server on port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, iis-7, jira

I know this can be done on Linux with JIRA, using mod_proxy, but I'm not sure if its possible on Windows:

Say we have a Windows server running IIS 7.0 and serving up pages on port 80, via an address like:

`http://twiddle.something.com`

We then install JIRA on the server, it uses its bundled Apache web server to serve stuff up on port 8080, like this:

`http://twiddle.something.com:8080`

Is there a way to configure IIS and Apache so that JIRA runs off a port 80 folder, as in:
`http://twiddle.something.com` still hits IIS
`http://twiddle.something.com/Jira` hits JIRA on Apache?

Thanks

edit: I guess we might also want to throw SSL into the mix for JIRA too....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done.  There is documentation on the Atlassian site about this:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+IIS

Another possibility if you are looking to reverse proxy the request is to use Application Request Routing (a supported IIS add-on):  http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting.